Mule Runtime 4.5 error with import in Munit
I am trying to develop a mule application with Mule runtime 4.5
It works fine in Anypoint studio , but whenever I try and build and deploy using Pipeline it fails with the error :
2024-04-05T01:42:26.1363950Z org.mule.runtime.api.exception.MuleRuntimeException: 
org.mule.runtime.core.api.config.ConfigurationException: [emp- 
test-suite.xml:9]: Could not find imported resource 'common\config.xml'

Here is the code for my Munit :
<munit:config name="emp-test-suite.xml" />
    
<import doc:name="Import" file="common\config.xml" />

config.xml is located in emp-service\src\test\munit\common\config.xml
So not sure why the import is failing only while executing from pipeline
If I run the Munits locally via Anypoint studio ( 7.16 ) it works fine and does not complain about the import
Edit1: Adding details of pom and mule-artifact.json
pom.xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>abc</groupId>
    <artifactId>emp-api-v1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>mule-application</packaging>
    <name>emp-api-v1</name>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <app.runtime>4.5.1</app.runtime>
        <mule.maven.plugin.version>4.0.0</mule.maven.plugin.version>
        <munit.version>2.3.14</munit.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mule.tools.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>mule-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${mule.maven.plugin.version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <sharedLibraries>
                        <sharedLibrary>
                            <groupId>com.oracle.ojdbc</groupId>
                            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
                        </sharedLibrary>
                    </sharedLibraries>
                    <classifier>mule-application</classifier>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.mulesoft.munit.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>munit-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${munit.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                            <goal>coverage-report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <coverage>
                        <runCoverage>true</runCoverage>
                        <formats>
                            <format>console</format>
                            <format>html</format>
                            <format>json</format>
                        </formats>
                    </coverage>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.connectors</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-db-connector</artifactId>
            <version>1.13.5</version>
            <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.connectors</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-objectstore-connector</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.connectors</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-http-connector</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0</version>
            <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-apikit-module</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.2</version>
            <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.munit</groupId>
            <artifactId>munit-runner</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.munit</groupId>
            <artifactId>munit-tools</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.weave</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertions</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.ojdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
            <version>19.3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>anypoint-exchange-v3</id>
            <name>Anypoint Exchange</name>
            <url>https://maven.anypoint.mulesoft.com/api/v3/maven</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>mulesoft-releases</id>
            <name>MuleSoft Releases Repository</name>
            <url>https://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>mulesoft-releases</id>
            <name>MuleSoft Releases Repository</name>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <url>https://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>anypoint-exchange</id>
            <distributionManagement>
                <repository>
                    <id>anypoint-exchange-v3</id>
                    <name>Corporate Repository</name>
                    <url>https://maven.anypoint.mulesoft.com/api/v3/organizations/${project.groupId}/maven</url>
                    <layout>default</layout>
                </repository>
            </distributionManagement>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>azure-artifacts</id>
            <distributionManagement>
                <repository>
                    <id>xyz-Mulesoft-Releases</id>
                    <url>https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/lmn/xyz/_packaging/xyz-Mulesoft-Releases/maven/v1</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </repository>
            </distributionManagement>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>

mule-artifact.json
    {
  "minMuleVersion": "4.5.0"
}

Edit2: Adding details about config.xml located in emp-service\src\test\munit\common\
Not sure if this helps but the file I am trying to import is also defined as a Munit here are its contents .
should this be defined as a normal mule configuration file and not a munit file ?
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>    
    <mule xmlns: .....>
    <munit:config name="config.xml" />
    
    <spring:config name="Spring_Config" doc:name="Spring Config"  files="beans.xml" />
</mule>


Which version of MUnit are you using and of the Mule Maven Plugin? Share the pom and mule-artifact.json files.

You might want to move the project to Mule 4.6. Mule 4.5 is a short-lived version which be end of life in June 2024.

have added pom.xml and mule-artifact.json details , mule maven plugin version is 4.0.0 and munit version is 2.3.14

also added details of the file am trying to import in munit

The version of MUnit does not support Mule 4.5. It needs MUnit >=3.0. You should use the latest release: https://docs.mulesoft.com/release-notes/munit/munit-release-notes

Thanks , changed Munit version to 3.0.0 and in logs can see the latest version being used : `

Started app 'emp-v1'                                       *
2024-04-08T22:03:48.3669831Z * Application plugins:                                               *
2024-04-08T22:03:48.3671985Z *  - MUnit : 3.0.0                                                   *
2024-04-08T22:03:48.3672687Z *  - MUnit Tools : 3.0.0                                             *` however still get the error regarding import


the file I am trying to import is really a wrapper for some datasources defined via spring . This imported file is created as a Munit file within src/test . Am wondering rather than a Munit should this imported file be a standard mule configuration file inside src/test ? i only want to use the imported file during tests

You can test it.

I converted the imported file from a munit file to a normal mule configuration file and placed it in \src\test\munit\common however was getting the same error , then tried placing the file in src\test\resources\ and it worked !

Please post it as a solution to help others.
